# Need to edit images name from directory,need to remove 10 digit number from all images

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, filenames

I have a folder of 1200 images. I want to rename all images in the folder so that the character at 10th place is removed.

For example, the image name 513017VQZR1A70 should be replaced with 513017VQZ1A70. Here the 10th character (R) is removed.

How I can  rename all images by removing 10 digit character?

Comment: This is a very basic task in Python. Show us the code you tried. If you haven't written any code, you should read some Python tutorial and at least make an attempt to write code.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert your path and you'll be good to go:

```
import os
os.chdir('path/to/folder/')

for file in os.listdir():
    os.rename(file,  file[0:9] + file[9 + 1:])
```

For all files in the directory, it renames them to the first to the 8th character, and the tenth to the last character. Basically, it strips the 9th character from all filenames.

Comment: if it solved your issue consider accepting the answer, or let me know how i can improve it